# Secure API .net core 3.1 (upgraded api from 2.2) with identityserver no longer works, is my middleware correct?

Tags: api, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an API (.net core 2.2) protected and working fine with Identity server.

I need to upgrade this API to .net core 3.1.  So I started fresh with a core 3.1 API project and added in the controllers, dbContext and the middleware... I have tried to match the middleware as close to the 2.2 as possible (which may be my problem) but I am receiving a 401 unauthorised on methods decorated with [Authorize] (without even declaring any roles or policies, just a simple Authorize).  If I take off the [Authorize] this works fine... so here lies the problem.

I have tried to find examples of upgrading the API from 2.2 to 3.1 from a middleware IdentityServer point of view, but only able to find examples of upgrading IdentityServer itself (not a protected API) between these versions.

I have also analysed the User claims in the API method, which all look fine.  This works fine on 2.2, so I think this must be to do with the middleware, but I'm not sure... can someone point me in the right direction please? Here is my startup file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using HMS.API.Services;
using HMS.Global.Repository;

namespace HMS.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            { 
                options.Authority = "https://????.???????.com"; // Removed for this post
                options.ApiName = "hmsapi";
                
            });

            services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HMSConnection")));

            // Create policy
            services.AddAuthorization(authorisationOptions =>
            {
                authorisationOptions
                .AddPolicy(
                    "HMSADMINPOLICY",
                    policyBuilder =>
                    {
                        policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                        policyBuilder.RequireClaim("role", "HMSADMIN");                        
                    });

                authorisationOptions
                .AddPolicy(
                    "HMSSTANDARDPOLICY",
                    policyBuilder =>
                    {
                        policyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                        policyBuilder.RequireClaim("role", "HMSSTANDARD", "HMSADMIN");
                    });
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to debug the traffic to/from my client application and especially look at the claims that are actually returned from IdentityServer.

If you are getting 401 not authorized when you just use [Authorize], then you are not really logged in. All users who are logged in should pass [Authorize].

If you are also upgrading to IdentityServer4 v4.0x , then you need to add your ApiScopes as well (New feature in v4.x)

Comment: This was great advice so I'm going to mark this as the answer, thank you for this... The problem was in IIS actually, changing ports from the old API to new and back again caused some issues, but after many many publishes and a full reboot of the PC, this seemed to fix the issue.  

Before this, I did use fiddler as you suggested. A little more complicated because I was using an Android phone to connect to the API. For anyone wanting to analyse your Android traffic, simply run fiddler on your PC. then using your android phone hold your Wifi icon in the top menu to show your connected network

Comment: hit the settings cog next to your connected network and click Advanced. Now in Proxy select Manual. The proxy host name is your PC ip address (find it using the command ipconfig in a cmd window) and the port is 8888 (fiddlers port)... that's it, your phone's traffic is now going through fiddler on your PC.

Comment: A good reference for capturing android traffic (including https) is https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-capture-android-traffic-with-fiddler